# Normalizing groups of columns in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have the following input table (accounts with payplans):

`account_number upfront_amount  hour_price  unlock_amount
    a1              10              2           150
    a2              10              2           150
    a3              12              1           140
    a4              20              1           140
    a5              20              1           140`

and I would like to create the following output tables:

account table:

`account_number payplanId
    a1              1
    a2              1
    a3              2
    a4              3
    a5              3`

payplans table:

```
id      upfront_amount  hour_price  unlock_amount
1               10              2           150
2               10              2           150
3               12              1           140
4               20              1           140
5               20              1           140
```

I am not sure how to approach this. With normalizer I can only normalize 1 column rather than multiple.

One other approach was first to make the payplan table with Unique Rows, but after I do that I don't know yet which account belongs to which payplan. Doing a lookup seems very cumbersome and I figure there has to be an easier to do this.

Would very much appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `Row normalizer` works for many columns, although it is cumbersome to parametrize.

Therefore, I usually use the `Unique Row` followed by a `Stream Lookup` at the main source, possibly followed by a `Group by`. It seams strange the first time you use it. On the second time you discover the flexibility of this pattern.

Comment: Thanks, it works! It is a bit slow though. Surprisingly enough using a LEFT OUTER merge join is faster. Maybe it has to do with my sorting. Will add more information in the future!

Comment: Since Pentaho 6 you do not need to sort anymore. There s a `Unique Row (Memory)` and `Group by (Memory)`which work very well for a small (1 million) number or records.